# is there an equivalent to tfa.image.dense_image_warp in keras or keras vision?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-addons, keras-cv

I am working with some custom layers and I am using tfa.image.dense_image_warp from tensorflow addons.

I was wondering if there is a similar or equivalent to this function in keras/keras vision?
I want to migrate to use keras instead.

is apply_affine_transform from affine_transformations.py (in Keras) same?